# Вставить Яндекс карту в Ворд документ

Tags: php, яндекс-карты

С PHP получается создать Ворд документ. Создаётся после обработки Excel файла. В файле есть поле адреса. Из этого адреса нужно сделать фото яндекс карты и вставить в файл. Это возможно?

Comment: А чем vba не устраивает? Я с помощью vba в excel вставил браузер, в него пихаю html-страницу с яндекс-картами с компа, которую сам генерирую (подкраска областей России в зависимости от параметров).

Comment: Чтобы отрисовать Я.Карту браузер выполняет JS-скрипт. В лучшем случае, вы можете переписать его исполнение на html… Или думать в [https://toster.ru/q/137713](другом направлении). А вообще, лучше VBA использовать или c# для такого и апелировать с «браузером»

Comment: в чем проблема получать картинку и вставлять куда надо ее? https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/staticapi/1.x/examples/index-docpage/